# Ruby on Rails - Nested Route Collections

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, routes, ruby-on-rails-5

I want to setup a GET endpoint in the format of:

> api/v1/users/types/{type_id}

Example: `> api/v1/users/types/10`

My current routing looks like this:

```
Rails.application.routes.draw do
  namespace :api do
    namespace :v1 do
      resources :users do
        collection do 
          # other routes in the same namespace
          get "sync"
          post "register"

          # my attempt at making another collection for `types`
          collection do
            get "types"
          end

        end
      end
    end
  end
end
```

This is incorrect and it throws an error: `ArgumentError: can't use collection outside resource(s) scope`. What's the correct formatting of routes for my requirement?

Comment: What controller method should handle that request? Do you care if the parameter is called `type_id` or just `id`.

Comment: @spickermann Not really concerned with the param name

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe the answer is:

```
Rails.application.routes.draw do
  namespace :api do
    namespace :v1 do
      resources :users do
        collection do
          get "sync"
          post "register"
          get "types/:type_id", action: 'types'
        end
      end
    end
  end
end
```

`types` is the action and what you need is the params `:type_id`.
if you run `rails routes`, you get:

```
      Prefix Verb   URI Pattern                            Controller#Action
             GET    /api/v1/users/types/:type_id(.:format) api/v1/users#types
```

Now you can go to `http://localhost:3000/api/v1/users/types/10`

Answer (score 2):

Try this

```
Rails.application.routes.draw do                                                                                                                 
  namespace :api do                                   
    namespace :v1 do                                  
      resource :users do                              
        resources :types, only: :show, param: :type_id
        collection do                             
          # other routes in the same namespace        
          get "sync"                                  
          post "register"                             
        end                                           
      end                                             
    end                                               
  end                                                 
end
```

Here I used resource instead of resources for user. And moved the types into resources.

Comment: This generated this > `/api/v1/users/: type_id/users/: type_id/types(.:format)`

Comment: Sorry but why is that?